# New column in Pandas dataframe based on value of variable in existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I am having difficulties creating a new column with a value that's based on the value of an existing column in that same dataframe.  The existing column is numeric and I'm trying give the new column a categorical value of high, medium, low based on something like:

low:  < (max-min)/3

med:  (max-min)/3 - (max-min)/3 *2

high:  > (max-min)/3 *2

Still learning Pandas, so any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:

This is what I have attempted:

```
df_unit_day_hour['Level_Score'] = pd.cut(df_unit_day_hour['Level_Score'], q=3, labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])
```

I think it's almost what I need, but I'm getting an error (KeyError).  Would it be because df_unit_day_hour['Level_Score'] is a float?

Comment: Please post raw input data, code to reproduce your df and the desired output, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want to recreate the [`Series.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.qcut.html) function

Consider this example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val':np.random.choice(10, 10)})
df['cat'] = pd.cut(df['val'], [-1,2,5,10], labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])
    df

   val   cat
0    6  high
1    2   low
2    7  high
3    7  high
4    8  high
5    8  high
6    9  high
7    6  high
8    2   low
9    0   low
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That seemed to put me on the right track, but I'm getting a KeyError.  I updated my post to show what I attempted.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user1624577, I updated my example to explain better how to use the cut/qcut functions.

Comment: Very much appreciated!  I could have done this in SAS in a couple of minutes, but I'm trying to break away from that platform.  Thanks again!